# mysql query with join

Tags: php, mysql, join, doctrine

this is my database:
[image]

I would retrieve all records in richiestepreventivo where idImpresa==xx and all the data in privati where privati.id==richiestepreventivo.idPrivato.
Can you explain me how I have to set the query with join?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM privati AS p
INNER JOIN richiestepreventivo AS r
      ON p.id = r.idPrivato
WHERE r.idImpresa = xx
```

Are you asking for a simple [inner join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/join.html)

Comment: yes I try in phpmyadmin and it works but with doctrine I have returned an error...see my post

Comment: i have posted a new question more specific:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027381/doctrine-unknow-relation-alias-on-innerjoin

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT r.id, p.data 
FROM richiestepreventivo r 
JOIN privati p ON p.id = r.idPrivato 
WHERE r.id = XX;
```

Comment: I'll leave that up to you, it shouldn't be that hard to translate.

Comment: $qr = Doctrine_Query::create()
                ->select('*')
                ->from('privati as p')
                ->innerJoin('richiestepreventivo as r ON p.id=r.idPrivato ')
                ->where('r.idImpresa=' . $idI);
it gives me Unknown relation alias